# USB Front Panel Connection To Motherboard With Separate Shield Pin

Tags: usb, connection, front-panel

I want to connect my case USB front panel connections to my motherboard.

Often plugs for this are in a 2x5 (female) block with one pin in the corner that can't be used so its a no-brainer to connect.

What about when its four cables like so:

```
4x1 (VCC, USB1-, USB1+, GND) block with a 1x1 shield.
4x1 (VCC, USB1-, USB1+, GND) block with a 1x1 shield.
4x1 (VCC, USB2-, USB2+, GND) block with a 1x1 shield.
4x1 (VCC, USB2-, USB2+, GND) block with a 1x1 shield.
```

Where does the shield pin belong?

So given pins like

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Is this the configuration?

```
cable #1 [Vcc][USB1-][USB1+][GND][Shield?]
cable #2 [Vcc][USB1-][USB1+][GND]
```

So cable 2's single shield connector is connected to nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three pins on the right side are GND. Put the shield pin on the top right one. You have it right. You could connect the spare shield pin to another GND pin elsewhere on the motherboard. Likely they are shorted together, so one connection is sufficient.

[image]

---

Previous Answer:

You want the shield pin connected to GND on the motherboard for EMC purposes. The front panel I/O can be a problem for Electromagnetic Radiation and tying the grounds together typically helps.

Comment: Great thanks for expanding your answer after my edit, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best diagram I've seen, but [this site](http://www.pctechguide.com/tutorials/MBoard_USB.htm) shows the pinout of the header.  Your connector should have the wires labeled.  Barring that, just look at the two end wires.  One is Vcc (+5V) and the other is ground, typically red and black respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really concerned about it, you can put a spare jumper over the shield pin on the mobo connector and use short wires to connect both 1x1 leads into it.